# "Add SSIS Connection Manager" Dialog Doesn't Contain Custom Connection Manager

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am attempting to create a custom connection manager for performing SFTP operations from within SSIS. I have completed implementation, strong-named my assembly and installed it in both the GAC and the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Connections folder. The problem is that the "Add SSIS Connection Manager" dialog doesn't show my new connection type and I'm at a loss as to how to diagnose this issue. So far I have ensured that Everyone has Full Control to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Connections folder.

Possibly related to this issue is that I cannot see the assembly when I browse the GAC, even though the gacutil program reports success when I run it to add the assembly.

What steps could I follow to diagnose the root cause of this issue? Is there anything else that I need to check to make it possible to add a add a custom connection manager?

**EDIT:** I should also note that the custom connection manager is compiled using .NET 4.0. This is why I cannot see the assembly in the GAC after installing it I believe, as the assembly is being placed in the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly folder rather than the %WINDIR%\assembly folder. I am using .NET 4.0 because of [this issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551532/cannot-build-project-in-2010-when-project-has-reference-to-ssis-2008-dlls-sqltask-manageddts-etc).

**EDIT #2:** It turns out that if I create my custom connection manager in a Visual Studio 2008 project, compiled against .NET 3.5 then everything works fine. (Apparently using Visual Studio 2008 is a workaround for the version issue linked above.) So the real question now is why the SSIS Designer doesn't pick up .NET 4.0 custom tasks and connection managers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add it to the toolbox? The doco has this as a mandatory step.

Also, you must close and reopen SSIS Designer after you install a new or new version of a custom object.

You could also try resetting the toolbox.

Comment: Connection managers aren't added to the toolbox. They appear when you click the "New Connection..." menu option in the "Connection Managers" region of the designer. Also closing and opening the designer does not change the behavior.